# Trying to pass a value to reserved byte

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I wanna pass "hello world" to the reserved "teste", but it just reads the first character of the string passed.

```
section .bss
    teste resb 1024

section .text
    global main

main:
    mov byte [teste], "hello world"

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, teste
    mov edx, 10
    int 0x80

exit_program:
    mov eax, 1      
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

I already tried changing from `byte` to `qword`, but it only add more 3 bytes and print "hell"

Comment: You either need to define it as a constant and copy it in a loop, or write blocks of 4 bytes. Obviously if you don't need it to be in `.bss` you can just pass the address of your constant (that you put into `.rodata` or `.data`).

Comment: @Jester actually it needs to be in `.bss` because I'm doing some tests. Do you have an example of code of what you suggested?

Comment: You can do `mov [teste], 'hell'; mov [teste+4], 'o wo'; mov [teste+8], 'rld'`

Comment: It worked, but if I have a long string it won't be trivial doing that way... Isn't there a better way of doing that?

Comment: We deal with variable length data structures using loops in code and declarations in data.  So, you might declare a (readonly) string in the data section that is loaded into memory as part of initial program instantiation, then use a loop in code to copy it somewhere at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already tried changing from `byte` to `qword`, but it only add more 3 bytes and print "hell"

In 32-bit programming you can't use a 64-bit immediate. You can do this in just 3 `dword` moves:

```
mov  ecx, teste
mov  dword [ecx], "hell"
mov  dword [ecx + 4], "o wo"
mov  dword [ecx + 8], "rld "
mov  eax, 4
mov  ebx, 1
mov  edx, 10
int  0x80
```

`mov  dword [ecx + 8], "rld"` is valid too. NASM will then zero-pad to write a full dword.

In order to display the whole message, use `mov edx, 11` (10 is one short).

> It worked, but if I have a long string it won't be trivial doing that way... Isn't there a better way of doing that?

If you had a long string it would already be in memory somewhere, wouldn't it? Then you just copy it to the `.bss`:

```
mov  edi, teste
mov  esi, message
mov  ecx, length
rep movsb

...

message  db 'This is a long string to copy elsewhere'
length   equ $ - message
```